# Image unable to be displayed on the UI after being stored in mongoDB as base64

Tags: typescript, mongodb, next.js13

I have been trying, to diplay an image on the UI using nextjs. I stored the image in the mongoDB as base64, now I want to retrieve it and turn it into a real image.

below is my model:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const PublisherSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  author_id: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please add author id'],
  },

  author_name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please add publisher name'],
  },
  article_title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please add title of your story'],
    unique:true,
  },

  article_summary: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please enter summary of your article'],
  },

  entire_article: {
    type: String,
  },
  
  article_image: {
    type: Buffer,
    required: [true, 'Please enter the image of this article'],
  },

  published_date: {
    type: Date,
    required: [true, 'Please enter date'],
  },
});



export default mongoose.models.Publisher || mongoose.model('Publisher', PublisherSchema);
```

as you can see article_image is a buffer.
now below is my endpoint to submit the data to the database:

```js
import connectDB from "@/app/utils/db";
import Publisher from "@/app/pages/api/models/publish_model";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  await connectDB();

  try {
    const reqBody = await request.json();

    const { author_id, author_name, article_title, article_summary,entire_article, article_image, published_date } = reqBody;

    const existingStory = await Publisher.findOne({ article_title });

    if (existingStory) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { message: "Article Already Exist" },
        { status: 400 }
      );
    }

    const newArticle = new Publisher({
      author_id,
      author_name,
      article_title,
      article_summary,
      entire_article,
      article_image,
      published_date,
    });

    const savedArticle = await newArticle.save();
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Article Added Successfully" },
      { status: 200 }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Internal server error", error },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

below is the form that accepts user data including the image:

```js
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import { Form, Button, Toast, Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import axios from "axios";
import Spinner from "react-bootstrap/Spinner";
import { FaArrowRight } from "react-icons/fa";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const WriteStoryForm = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const authToken = Cookies.get("auth_token");
  let userId;

  if (authToken) {
    try {
      const tokenData = JSON.parse(authToken);
      userId = tokenData.userId;
      console.log("User ID:", userId);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error parsing token data:", error);
    }
  } else {
    console.error("No authentication token found in cookies");
  }

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    author_id: userId,
    author_name: "",
    article_title: "",
    article_summary: "",
    entire_article: "",
    article_image: null as string | null,
    published_date: "",
  });


  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState("");

  const handleImageChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const fileInput = e.target;

    if (fileInput) {
      const file = fileInput.files ? fileInput.files[0] : null;

      if (file) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        
        reader.onload = (event) => {
          if (event.target) {
            setFormData({
              ...formData,
              article_image: event.target.result as string,
            });
          }
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      const response = await axios.post("../pages/api/summary", formData);

      if (response.status === 200) {
        setSuccess("Story Saved Successfully");
        localStorage.setItem('article_title', formData.article_title);
        handleNavigation();
      } else if (response.status === 400) {
        setError("Story Already Published");
      }
    } catch (err: any) {
      setError(err.response.data.message);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const handleNavigation = () => {
    router.push("/views/write-article");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Card>
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title className="text-center">Summarise Your Story</Card.Title>
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Author Name</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                name="author_name"
                value={formData.author_name}
                onChange={handleChange}
                placeholder="Add Author Name"
                required
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Article Title</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                name="article_title"
                value={formData.article_title}
                onChange={handleChange}
                placeholder="Add Article Title"
                required
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
              <Form.Label className="mb-2">Article Body</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                as="textarea"
                name="article_summary"
                rows={5}
                placeholder="Summarise your story here....."
                style={{
                  borderRadius: "10px",
                  borderColor: "#ccc",
                  padding: "10px",
                  fontSize: "16px",
                }}
                value={formData.article_summary}
                onChange={handleChange}
                required
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Article Image</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="file"
                name="article_image"
                accept="image/*"
                onChange={handleImageChange}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group controlId="published_date">
              <Form.Label>Published Date</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="date"
                name="published_date"
                value={formData.published_date}
                onChange={handleChange}
                required
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button
              className="btn btn-dark"
              type="submit"
              style={{
                marginTop: "10px",
                marginLeft: "40%",
              }}
              disabled={isLoading}
            >
              {isLoading ? (
                <>
                  <Spinner
                    as="span"
                    animation="border"
                    size="sm"
                    role="status"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  />
                  Saving...
                </>
              ) : (
                "Save Article Summary and Continue"
              )}
            </Button>
          </Form>
          <Toast
            show={!!success}
            onClose={() => setSuccess("")}
            delay={3000}
            autohide
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              top: "20px",
              right: "20px",
              color: "white",
            }}
            bg="success"
          >
            <Toast.Header closeButton={false}>
              <strong className="me-auto">Success</strong>
            </Toast.Header>
            <Toast.Body>{success}</Toast.Body>
          </Toast>

          <Toast
            show={!!error}
            onClose={() => setError("")}
            delay={3000}
            autohide
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              top: "20px",
              right: "20px",
              color: "white",
            }}
            bg="danger"
          >
            <Toast.Header closeButton={false}>
              <strong className="me-auto">Error</strong>
            </Toast.Header>
            <Toast.Body>{error}</Toast.Body>
          </Toast>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
};

export default WriteStoryForm;
```

after inserting the image inside the mongoDB it stores it as a binary, now I need help with an endpoint to display it on the UI as the real image, below is the endpoint I made to retrieve image from the mongodb:

```js
import connectDB from "@/app/utils/db";
import Publisher from "@/app/pages/api/models/publish_model";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  await connectDB();

  const articles = await Publisher.find({});

  try {
    if (articles.length === 0) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { message: "No Articles released yet!" },
        { status: 401 }
      );
    }

  

    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Article Returned Successfully", articles},
      { status: 200 }
    );

  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Internal server error", error },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

below is what I tried to diplay it on a ui:

```js
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { Container, Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import styles from "@/app/styles/article.module.css";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";




interface ArticlesData {
  _id:string;
  author_name: string;
  article_title: string;
  article_summary: string;
  article_image: string;
  entire_article: string;
  published_date: string;
}

const ArticleCard: React.FC = () => {
    const router = useRouter(); 
   const [showFullContent, setShowFullContent] = useState(false);
  
  const [articlesData, setArticlesData] = useState<ArticlesData[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState<{ [key: number]: boolean }>(
    {}
  );

  const toggleContent = (index: number) => {
    if (showContent[index]) {
      router.back();
    } else {
      router.push(`/views/article/${articlesData[index]._id}`);
    }
  };

  const formatPublishedDate = (dateString: string) => {
    const options: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = {
      day: "2-digit",
      month: "2-digit",
      year: "numeric",
      hour: "2-digit",
      minute: "2-digit",
      second: "2-digit",
    };
    return new Date(dateString).toLocaleString("en-GB", options);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        setTimeout(async () => {
          const response = await fetch("pages/api/publish-article");
          if (!response) {
            throw new Error("No articles yet");
          }
          const data = await response.json();
          if (Array.isArray(data.articles)) {
            setArticlesData(data.articles);
            const initialShowContentState: { [key: number]: boolean } =
              data.articles.reduce(
                (acc: any, _: any, index: any) => ({ ...acc, [index]: false }),
                {}
              );
          
            setShowContent(initialShowContentState);
          } else {
            throw new Error("Data.articles is not an array");
          }
          setLoading(false);
        }, 2000);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);


  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <div className="text-center" style={{ marginTop: "25%" }}>
          {" "}
          {/* Center the spinner */}
          <div className="spinner-border spinner-border-lg" role="status">
            <span className="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : articlesData.length > 0 ? (
        articlesData.map((articles, index) => (
          <Container className={styles.articleContainer} key={index}>
            <Card>
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{articles.article_title}</Card.Title>
                <div
                  style={{
                    position: "relative",
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "200px",
                    marginBottom: "10px",
                  }}
                >
                  <p>{articles.article_image.toString()}</p>
                 <Image
                    src={articles.article_image}
                    alt=""
                    layout="fill"
                    objectFit="cover"
                  />
                </div>
                <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">
                  Author: {articles.author_name}
                </Card.Subtitle>
                <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">
                  Published on: {formatPublishedDate(articles.published_date)}
                </Card.Subtitle>
                <Card.Text>
                  {showContent[index]
                    ? articles.article_summary
                    : articles.article_summary.slice(0, 500) + "..."}
                </Card.Text>
                {articles.article_summary.length > 500 && (
                  <Button
                    variant="primary"
                    onClick={() => toggleContent(index)}
                  >
                    {showContent[index] ? "Read Less" : "Read  More"}
                  </Button>
                )}
                <p className="card-text">
                  <small className="text-muted"></small>
                </p>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          </Container>
        ))
      ) : (
        <p>No Article data available.</p>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ArticleCard;
```